# Hystrix: Custom circuit breaker and recovery logic

Tags: java, fault-tolerance, hystrix

I just read the [Hystrix](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-it-Works) guide and am trying to wrap my head around how the default circuit breaker and recovery period operate, and then how to customize their behavior.

Obviously, if the circuit is tripped, Hystrix will automatically call the command's `getFallBack()` method; this much I understand. But what criteria go into making the circuit tripped in the first place? Ideally, I'd like to try hitting a backing service several times (say, a max of 3 attempts) before we consider the service to be offline/unhealthy and trip the circuit breaker. **How could I implement this, and where?**

But I imagine that if I override the default circuit breaker, I must also override whatever mechanism handles the default recovery period. If a backing service goes down, it could be for any one of several reasons:

- There is a network outage between the client and server
- The service was deployed with a bug that makes it incapable of returning valid responses to the client
- The client was deployed with a bug that makes it incapable of sending valid requests to the server
- Some weird, momentary service hiccup (perhaps the service is doing a major garbage collection, etc.)
- etc.

In most of these cases, it is not sufficient to have a recovery period that merely waits *N* seconds and then tries again. If the service has a bug in it, or if someone pulled some network cables in the data center, we will *always* get failures from this service. Only in a small number of cases will the client-service automagically heal itself without any human interaction.

So I guess my next question is partially "**How do I customize the default recovery period strategy?**", but I guess it is mainly: "**How do I use Hystrix to notify devops when a service is down and requires manual intervention?**"

Answer (score 34, accepted):

there are basically **four reasons for Hystrix to call the fallback method**: an exception, a timeout, too many parallel requests, or too many exceptions in the previous calls.

You might want to do a retry in your run() method if the return code or the exception you receive from your service indicate that a retry makes sense.

In your fallback method of the command you might retry when there was a timeout - when there where too many parallel requests or too many exceptions it usually makes no sense to call the same service again.

As also asked **how to notify devops**: You should connect a monitoring system to Hystrix that polls the status of the circuit breaker and the ratio of successful and unsuccessful calls. You can use the [metrics publishers](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Metrics-and-Monitoring#metrics-publisher) provided, JMX, or write your own adapter using Hystrix' API. I've written two adapters for Riemann and Zabbix in a [tutorial I prepared](https://github.com/ahus1/hystrix-examples); you'll new very few lines of code for that.

The tutorial also has a example application and a load driver to try out some scenarios.

Br, 
Alexander.

Comment: Excellent answer @ahus1 (+1) - just curious here: is there a way to control the circuit breaker's re-closing if the target service becomes healthy again? In other words, say a service is down for a few minutes: hopefully the circuit breaker trips and opens. Now, all calls to the service will result with `getFalllback` executing. But now the service becomes healthy again. How does Hystrix know to close the circuit breaker and allow `run` to execute again?

Comment: @IAmYourFaja: The circuit breaker will trigger when there are a lot of errors (by default: more than 50% errors in a time frame). After that all requests will be handled by the fallback (if one is available). After some seconds (default: 5 seconds) a single request is forwarded to the original service first. If this is successful, all the circuit is closed again and requests are forwarded to the original service again. See https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration for configuration values. See https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-it-Works#CircuitBreaker for functionality.

Comment: The recovery check does not happen every 5 seconds as per the default. Every time the original service is invoked and on FAILURE the fallback is invoked . Any body has faced this issue ?